# How to insert data in MySQL with jQuery and Ajax without page refresing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an index.php page that contains a form & an input button,
and use this script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#first_name").val();
    var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
    var city_name = $("#city_name").val();
    var dataString = 'first_name='+name+'&last_name='+last_name+'&city_name='+city_name;
    $.ajax({
        data:dataString,
        url:'index.php',
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

FORM

```
<form method="post" id="reg-form">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><a href="index.php">back to main page</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="city_name" id="city_name" placeholder="City" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Update" id="update1" value="SAVE" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I would like to store the form data into database without refreshing the page when I click the insert button.

Comment: And where is your code that has a databse connection and a query to insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use form submit event for handling form submition

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reg-form").submit(e) { //submit event occur when you submit your form
        e.preventDefault(); //this will prevent reloading and default form submission 
        var name = $("#first_name").val();
        var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
        var city_name = $("#city_name").val();
        var dataString = 'first_name=' + name + '&last_name=' + last_name + '&city_name=' + city_name;
        $.ajax({
            data: dataString,
            url: 'index.php',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

> You are sending ajax request on document.ready instead of when form
>   submitted.

Comment: How does this answer his question?

Comment: @Naruto i think you can't see answer properly. OP didn't use form submit event. He is sending data on `document.ready`.

Comment: @Naruto Hahaha. nice one.

Comment: @Manwal that is js code can you write php code for OP too.

Answer (score 2):

am using this insert Query in index.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['Update'])){
    $fname = $_POST['first_name'];  
    $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $cityname = $_POST['city_name'];
    $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name,user_city) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$cityname')");
    if(is_scalar($query1)){
        echo "Insert Sucssesfulyy";die;
    }        
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle form submit, you can use `$( "#reg-form" ).submit(function(event)`

To prevent loading, use `event.preventDefault();`

The result is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#reg-form" ).submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var name = $("#first_name").val();
            var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
            var city_name = $("#city_name").val();
            var dataString = 'first_name=' + name + '&last_name=' + last_name + '&city_name=' + city_name;
            $.ajax({
                data: dataString,
                url: 'index.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is alot of missing stuff here but let me tell you what to do generally:

in your index.php:

1. Check if you get POST request then init the DB save functionality. I would use doctrine or at least PDO to save/update data.

   `if($_POST['Update'] == 'SAVE'){ // Do DB work}`
2. On front-end side, do AjAX to that page with type POST. you can use:

   `var formData = jQuery('#reg-form').serialize();`

and then use it in the Ajax call :

`type: 'POST',
data:formData,`

Hope it helps.

Comment: tanks @Tareq Al-Zubaidi

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery as mentioned in answers, but why invent the wheal again? 
There is a jQuery form plugin which handles the submitting forms. You dont have to write down that long JS code. It is simple, easy to use and provides multiple data formats. Please check it at below link:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Hope that will help you and will make your work easy :) .

Answer (score 0):

If you use this PHP code

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['Update'])){
    $fname = $_POST['first_name'];  
    $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $cityname = $_POST['city_name'];
    $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name,user_city) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$cityname')");
    if(is_scalar($query1)){
        echo "Insert Sucssesfully";
    }
    else{
        echo "Insert aborted";
    }
}
?>
```

And this markup

```
<form method="post" id="reg-form">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><a href="index.php">back to main page</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="city_name" id="city_name" placeholder="City" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Update" id="update1" value="SAVE" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Then the best way to send data (according to me) is to use [Jquery .load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

The sript result is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#reg-form" ).submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var name = $("#first_name").val();
            var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
            var city_name = $("#city_name").val();
            $( "#result" ).load(
                     //The URL of the action page
                    "index.php",
                     //Datas to sent as an Array [name:value]
                    {Update:true,first_name:name,last_name:last_name,city_name:city_name},
                     //OnComplete function
                    function() {
                        alert( "Datas sent" );
                    }
                );
        });
    });
</script>
```